# Post-Order Review Experience

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior, e-commerce, ratings

For a food ordering mobile app, looking to obtain user feedback on the order collection experience, and trying to determine the best time/place to ask for this in the app.

The app requires users to press a button when their order is complete; as such, exploring two options:

1. After a user 'completes' their order, display a modal or interstitial asking for their rating
2. The next time the user opens the app, prompt them to rate their previous experience at X restaurant

The con I see with #2 is that it may take users away from their intended use of the app when launching it.

Open to any other recommendations as well!

Comment: Is it possible to add on incentives? Maybe if there was some sort of loyalty system that rewarded the user with discounts or something they could use in part payment for food, you could add credit for answering surveys about previous meals - this could effectively become a destination in itself: user decides to earn some credit by completing surveys about previous meals.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases you are asking for the consumer to go away from what he is intending to do and do you a favor by accurately rating his experience.

The advantage of doing this immediately after the user completes his task is that the experience is fresh in his mind.

In a choice between option one and option two I would select option one for that very reason. If you did things that irritated the user, then he is prompted to immediately give you his feedback. Furthermore if the user was extremely irritated and frustrated with your site he might never have returned and you would not get the feedback.  (Don't be surprised by negative feedback. These surveys are not there for you to get a pat on the head.)

Andrew Martin, in his comment, gave the best solution. Do not take the user out of his workflow. Do not ask the user to do you a favor with nothing tangible in return.  Give a reward for completing the task. Gamify the process. At this point ideas should be popping in your head

- how to show rewards
- where should it lead the user
- how to entice the user to leave useful feedback
- how many questions to ask at one time, and what to leave for future rewards

and, of course,

- what rewards does one give?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first option you propose is better than the 2nd.

- In the 2nd, the user will be **out of her workflow**, and ask for maybe a 3 days or even weeks old action is not a good idea imo: it would be **frustrating** for the user because she won't be able to do immediately what she aimed to do when using your app.
- In the 1st option, that's **much better** the way you thought it could be in the user flow: after everything completed, and hopefully an amazing experience through your product, the user is much more ready to be kind and give you feedback.
  It should not stop the user in her flow; I mean, you can probably add a call to action to invite the user answer your questions, but the modal or pop up might not be the best solution. It creates frustration and it's called ***modal excise***, which is right in front the user without her consent, and she can not do anything else until she deals with the modal (one action to do too many)

Hope I helped you ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Does the user rating have an effect on the delivery driver or restaurant? E.g. bad service providers are flagged or given lower priority, like in rideshare apps. Showing users how their feedback is going to be used is a form of incentive and that could mitigate the con of taking them out of the workflow. I find app store ratings annoying because it not only takes me out of my workflow but there's nothing in it for. Food delivery is a different thing and  judging from social media postings, forums and online news, people have a lot to say about food and food delivery service.

By the way, how do you determine that the order is complete? Is it a notification that appears when the delivery person indicates that the job is complete? When that happens, the user is likely to be busy with the food and might ignore it. 
I think #2 will also work as an email message.